# Integrity constraint violation. There is no Contradiction. Laravel

Tags: laravel

How can I resolve this error?
I cannot seem to find there is Integrity constraint violation.

Error :

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
> constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign
> key constraint fails (`kondate`.`created_kondates_foods`, CONSTRAINT
> `created_kondates_foods_food_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`food_id`)
> REFERENCES `foods` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `created_kondates_foods`
> (`created_kondate_id`, `food_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values
> (34, 6655, 2022-04-05 19:00:31, 2022-04-05 19:00:31)) in file
> /Users/Developments/kondate/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php
> on line 669

My codes :

```
class CreatedKondate extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'kondate';

    protected $table = 'created_kondates';

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function foods()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Food', 'created_kondates_foods', 'created_kondate_id', 'food_id');
    }
}
```

a model of Intermediate table　.

CreatedKondateFood

```
class CreatedKondateFood extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'kondate';

    protected $table = 'created_kondates_foods';

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

}
```

Database output function

```
 $first_date = date("2022-04-01");
 $end_date = date("2022-04-t");

        for($i = $first_date; $i<=$end_date ;$i++)
        {
            $createdKondate = new CreatedKondate;
            $createdKondate->company_id = $company_id;
            $createdKondate->calendar_date = $i;
            $createdKondate->save();

        $createdKondateFood = new CreatedKondateFood;
        $createdKondateFood->created_kondate_id = $createdKondate->id;
        $createdKondateFood->food_id = '6655';
        $createdKondateFood->save();
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you replace

```php
    $createdKondateFood->food_id = '6655';
```

by

```php
    $createdKondateFood->food_id = 6655;
```

It may also comes from the fact that there's no item having its id set to 6655 in the food table